# what will be fast way of finding the live hosts on network?

Tags: network, arp, traffic

what will be fastest way to find the live hosts on network. Currently i am finding the live network hosts using arp request and arp response. I have to find these live hosts every second. Is there any efficient way to find the live hosts quickly? and will finding live hosts using arp request and arp response will make a huge traffic on network and will make my system highlighted on network. Your answer will be appreciated.

Comment: There really is no guaranteed way to find other hosts on a network. There are things like Private VLANs where it is not even possible, and some hosts can be configured to not respond.

Comment: @RonMaupin but what if no host is configured not to respond then ?

Comment: Then you will need to send and receive a lot of traffic on the network (as long as it is not a Private VLAN), and this is normally frowned upon on company networks (you could be disciplined at some companies). It really is not possible for some very large networks. Remember for IPv6 the standard `/64` network has 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 possible addresses, and at an unlikely 1,000,000 scans per second, it would take over 584,542 years!

Comment: @RonMaupin scaning for just 254 hosts 192.168.10.0/24 what will be affect on network ?

Comment: @RonMaupin will my activities will be suspicious and can easily spoted?

Comment: @RisenStar If you ARP 254 host addresses each second, the broadcast rate would (or should) raise a warning. But of course, networks not under your control are explicitly off topic here.

Comment: 254 broadcast/sec wouldn't catch anything's attention. (for the record, my cablemodem is spewing over 300 per second, 24/7) Any *human* watching would (should?) have an issue with it, but no storm-control or IDS will care. (if an IDS takes issue with it, it will the obvious scan, not the broadcast rate)

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the switches that connect the hosts, and they are manageable, you can query the MAC address table of the switches to check all the MAC addresses seen on the network.

You can reconcile the MAC address with the IP address by looking at the ARP (for IPv4) or Neighbor (for IPv6) tables on the routers.

Comment: Yes the proper way to account for devices on the network is to 'ask the network' not to ask all the devices possible whether they exist. You need to use the management features of the network infrastructure.

Comment: Depends on what OP considers "live" and "network". I have overlapping layer-3's on the same layer-2, and some layer-2 only devices (oddball ethernet-serial adapters connected to diag ports of tape drives); good luck finding all of them :-)

Answer (score 0):

nmap scan will give you what you need.  You couls use it in a script.
Or you could use a product like netdisco.

That being said, every second seems kind of excessive.  Normal network polling is ~5 minutes.

Comment: Product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.